# how to register calss in php-di to automatically call some method when instantiated

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

i run controller this way

```
$controller = $this->getContainer()->get($class);
$controller->{$method}(...array_values($vars));
```

now inside controller i need to use models
if i try to autowire model like

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    public function doSmth(myModel $myModel)
    {
           $myModel->getAll());
    }
}
```

i receive error about wrong parameter types.
controller methods shouldnt always use some model and because of this models need to be instantiated inside methods .

ok, then im trying to 
instantiate model directly

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    public function doSmth()
    {
           $myModel = new myModel();
           $myModel->getAll());
    }
}
```

but i receive problem that i need instance of the container inside the model (to set up DB connection for example, and these settings registered inside container).
i could transfer the container instance from the controller to the model like this:

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    public function doSmth()
    {
           $myModel = new myModel($this->container);
           $myModel->getAll());
    }
}
```

but i would have to do this every time i need some model and this is ugly ...

im new to the php-di. i know that when im instantiating inside the method DI doesnt track it  ...
just dont know how to set this altogether ?

Answer (score 0):

since Controller has an instance of the container required just to call the model through container and wrap it in some method like **getModel($modelName)**

```
class MyClass extends Controller
{
    public function doSmth()
    {
        $myModel = $this->getModel('MyModel');
        $myModel->getAll());
    }
}
```

and get model will be smth like:

```
class Controller
{
    protected $c;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $c)
    {
        $this->c = $c;
    }

    public function getModel(string $name)
    {
        return $this->c->get($name);
    }
}
```